# Javascript compare two JSON arrays and return key of the unmatched value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash, difference

I have two JSON arrays, would like to know the key which don't match. I don't need the value.

Example:

```
livetable: [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "John" },
],
backupTable: [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "Peter" },
],
```

I can get the key/value pair which is diffrent with this Lodash script:

```
difference = _.differenceWith(livetable,backupTable,_.isEqual)
```

But I would just need the key, in this example "name" for "id: 2" is not matching, so I would need to get the "name" key to new array/variable.

(Using VUE CLI)

EDIT: Added example of current code output.

```js
var livetable = [{"id": 1, "name": "Sandra", "id": 2, "name": "John"}]
var backupTable = [{"id": 1, "name": "Sandra", "id": 2, "name": "Peter"}]

console.log(_.differenceWith(backupTable,livetable,_.isEqual))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This will output the key:value pair, but I would just need the key which is diffrent.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (What you've quoted would be invalid JSON if it were JSON; in JSON, property names must be in double quotes.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Hi, the JSON is not a problem. I know how it's formatted. My main question is how to compare two JSON arrays and filter out the key-s if value don't match with main JSON. 

Updated my post with working JS example.

Comment: Your last example: `{"id": 1, "name": "Sandra", "id": 2, "name": "John"}` does not equal the first example.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I know. This is the whole point of my question to get the "key" of the unmatching values.

Comment: No, it is not possible to have Two ids and two names in the same object! `[{"id": 1, "name": "Sandra", "id": 2, "name": "John"}]` is not `[{"id": 1, "name": "Sandra"}, {"id": 2, "name": "John"}]`

Comment: @Tom - Because they're formatting JavaScript, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  There are some unknowns though, like what should happen if there is a missing record in the second data set?

This solution assumes each table of data has the same amount of records and the records have the same IDs.

```js
// define data
const livetable = [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "John" }
]
const backupTable = [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "Peter" }
]


const getDifferentRecordsByID = (sourceRecords, compareRecords) => {
  // simple utility function to return a record object matching by ID
  const findComparisionRecord = id => compareRecords.find(compareRecord => compareRecord.id === id)
  // using the utility function, we can filter out any mismatching records by comparing name
  return sourceRecords
    .filter(sourceRecord => sourceRecord.name !== findComparisionRecord(sourceRecord.id).name)
    // then map over all the records and just pull out the ID
    .map(record => record.id)
}

console.log(getDifferentRecordsByID(livetable, backupTable)) // [2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try this. 
Well overall I have few mysql tables and I have built frontend software in VUE to make 
 changes in database. We will backup a table, then make changes in the original table and if needed we can restore data from the backup table. All happens in VUE/Express. To make it easier for others co-workes, I would like to add option to easily spot which SQL columns are not matching so they can restore only these columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working VUE code for my problem.
Function returns `[ "name" ]`, which is exactly what I need.

```
data() {
    return {
      livetable: [{ id: 1, name: "Sandra" },{ id: 2, name: "John" }],
      backupTable: [{ id: 1, name: "Sandra" },{ id: 2, name: "Peter" }],
      difColumns: null,
    };
  },
methods: {
    test3() {
      let resultArray = []
      this.livetable.forEach((array1, index) => {
        const array2 = this.backupTable[index];
        resultArray.push(this._.reduce(array1, (result, value, key) => this._.isEqual(value, array2[key]) ? result : result.concat(key), []))
      });
      this.difColumns = resultArray[0]
    }
},
```